# how to insert image in sqlite database in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to insert image in database, I tried to but its not inserting. Where is the problem in query? This is my model class .m file: code in this file after `sqlite3_prepare_v2` my trace is not inserting in `sqlite3_bind_blob` it is going directly outside after `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. What is the problem here, please help me. Something is wrong here for saving the data. In model class i create `UIImage* Photo;` and make protocol and sys

```
+(void)SaveImagesToSql:(NSData *)imgDat :(int)getid
{
    NSString *filePath = [BaseModal getDBPath];
    sqlite3 *database;
    sqlite3_stmt *updStmt;
    NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
    if (sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    { 
        NSString* sqliteQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE INTO Peoples (Photo) VALUES (?) where PeopleId =%i",getid];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqliteQuery UTF8String] , -1, &updStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    {

            sqlite3_bind_blob(updStmt, 1, [imgDat bytes], [imgDat length], NULL);

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(updStmt);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

this is my view.m file i am choosing image from this page and insert in to sqlite file

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image, self, nil, nil);

    NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", docDirectory];
    NSLog(@"thiss%@",filePath);
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    if(picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) {    
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);   
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        return;
    } 


    [picker release];
    UIImage *image1 =imageView.image;
    NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);

    [PeopleModal SaveImagesToSql:myData :peopleid]; 

    //[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];



}
```

Comment: don't store data in database.ave image in document directory and then save that path in database ...

Answer (score 3):

You should not insert blobs in db, this will make your db very very slow!!

You should save the image in documents directory of the app and in the db save only the path of the image.